# Neo4J Trying to find all nodes with matching property values

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I have a DB with students and courses that they're attending. The objective is to find all students with the same lastname that attent the same courses and return their firstNames and courseNames. `(s:Student)-[r:ENROLLEDIN]->(c:Course)`

I've tried a bunch of stuff out of my head but I believe I'm still thinking SQL.

How do I compare the same property values across the nodes of the same class taking into account a relation? I've googled it, no answer found though.

Try not to minus me too much, I've just started learning this thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/02/17/neo4jcypher-sql-style-group-by-functionality/

Comment: I think that you should more specifically describe the desired result.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want back? Do you want, for each individual course, the first names of all the students that have the same last name? Or are you looking for results that cover all the common courses taken by those with the same last name? Or something else? Once you make the desired output and behavior clear, we can get  you a more accurate query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple query to find all students with the same last name that attend the same course :

```
MATCH (s1:Student)-[:ENROLLEDIN]->(c1:Course),(s2:Student)-[:ENROLLEDIN]->(c2:Course)
WHERE s1.lastName = s2.lastName AND c1.name = c2.name
RETURN DISTINCT s1.firstName, c2.name ORDER BY s1.firstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this query should work:

```
// match students and courses when students have the same name
MATCH (s1:Student)-[:ENROLLEDIN]->(c1:Course),
        (s2:Student)-[:ENROLLEDIN]->(c2:Course)
WHERE s1.lastname = s2.lastname
// order by c1
WITH s1, s2, c1, c2 ORDER BY c1
// collect c1 as c1s, order by c2
WITH s1, s2, c2, collect(c1) AS c1s ORDER BY c2
// collect c2 as c2s. Pass to the next context when
// c1s = c2s. The array order matters.
WITH s1, s2, collect(c2) as c2s, c1s 
WHERE c1s = c2s
RETURN s1.firstName, s2.firstName, c1s
```